# What Is The Benefit Of Moving Gradle Build Code To Plugins?

Tags: gradle

I work with a third party Java application that supplies a gradle build to package the application with customisations on site.

However, recently they have been moving code from the build.gradle files to compiled plugins.

This is annoying for me as I can no longer understand how the build works since the majority is in undocumented plugins.

Apart from hiding the code (not sure why you need to hide the code in build scripts...) is there a benefit to moving to plugins - especially when the plugins are not reused anywhere else?

e.g.

can you do things in plugins that you can't do in normal build.gradle scripts?

will the build run faster when using compiled plugings vs having the same code in build.gradle scripts?

For reference, most of the build is unzipping/zipping war files and signing jars.

Comment: To answer the parts of this question, that are not *opinion-based*: No, you can't do things in a plugin you could not also do in the build script (beside using Java), and, yes, compiled plugins [are indeed faster](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#statically_compile_tasks_and_plugins).

Comment: This question also leads to a general question in software development: Why should I develop (or use) a library or package instead of just copy-pasting the code to wherever I need it?

Answer (score 0):

Functionally you cannot do anything in plugins that you cannot do in gradle files. Syntactically however there are some things you can do with plugins that would not be possible with gradle files.

As an example a File `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/Main.groovy` will automatically be available in all gradle scripts. The `buildSrc` folder is special that way.

For complex groovy code, developing them as plugins also allows to run static code checkers, unit tests, and similar tools to improve the quality of the plugin code, which is more difficult to do with code in  gradle files.

Also, compiled plugins can be faster.